# error " could not find function "List"

Tags: r

Getting error with the below code in R. Please help.

```
customer<-scan("E:/Data science course/R/practice/customers.csv",              
          what=List(First_name="",
                    Last_name="",
                    City="", county="", state="",zip=0),
          sep=",", skip=1,)
```

Comment: I think you wanted to use `list` instead of `List`

Comment: `"1. Did you write the name of your function correctly? Names are case sensitive."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use list(). List() doesn't appear in any packages.
Best regards

Comment: yes, this solved the error. thank you very much